# Adding Traditional Chinese (Zhuyin) Keyboard input on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: keyboard-layout, input-method, chinese

In input keyboards to choose from in settings, there see only 1 Chinese keyboard and it's a Pinyin one. In HK and Taiwan they use bopomofo (Zhuyin) and I'd like to have it. It's a phonetic alphabet and the keyboards can have these symbols printed. They look like this:

[image: Zhuyin keyboard]

As you type you get character suggestion. Characters are also different - they are Traditional Chinese characters - pre-Cultural Revolution.
Is this something that is included in Ubuntu and I can't find it. And if it isn't could I suggest to add it to make Ubuntu more inclusive?
Please help.
I also wanted to tag it Zhuyin and Traditional-Chinese, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: There is indeed support for traditional Chinese as well. For instance, if you have the `ibus-libpinyin` package installed, there is a _Chinese (Bopomofo)_ choice in settings, and that's a ZhuYin input method.

Comment: Thank you @GunnarHjalmarsson, that did indeed work. Thank you very much. But the keyboard behaves not as expected, unlike the phone keyboard, when you get suggestion characters before you complete the whole sequence. Including the one of the 4 tones at the end is a major handicap. Slows down typing and expects you to get a 100% correct bopomofo spelling before making suggestions. Ubuntu also only gives a list of options after you enter the accent, and you can only enter the one of numbers 1, 2, 3 etc for a corresponding Chinese character option. Any tips on how to fix these 2 problems?

Comment: (after installing ibus-libpinyin, Chinese (Taiwan) option appeared).

Comment: I don't speak Chinese, so can't really discuss how to use the thing. But there are other options; you may want to install `ibus-chewing`. Then after next login a Chewing input method should be selectable in Settings.

Comment: Thank you very much for this @GunnarHjalmarsson! A "Chinese (intelligent pinyin)" option showed up and it does excellent with suggestions. So it is very valuable to me. One thing is it is pinyin not zhuyin. It is easier for me, of course, but I'd like zhuyin keyboard to be able to do the same. However, the settings icon on the zhuin keybord in settings is unresponsive and doesn't open anything, unlike the "intelligent pinyin" option which opens up to all sorts of possible tweaks.